# Pass injectable service to the parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Using **Angular 12**

I want to create a base component class that will have common functionalities like getting the list of objects from the endpoint, pagination, etc., etc.,

**Parent Class**

```js
class BaseComponent<T> implements onInIt {
  itemsList: Array<T>;

  constructor(
    private itemService: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getList();
  }

  getList() {
    this.itemService.list().subscribe(res => {
      this.itemsList = res;
    });
  }
  }
}
```

Each child component extends the **BaseComponent** where **T** is the interface of the type of object represented by the child class.

Example

```js
// UserModel
export interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

export interface Payment {
  id: string;
  user: User;
  amount: number;
}
```

The **UserComponent** would be

```js
export class UserComponent extends BaseComponent<User> {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) {
    super();   <---
  }

}
```

I want to pass `userService` to the `itemService` in the parent component so that it could use the `list()` method from this service.

**How can I pass injectable service to the parent component class?**

> Error

```
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token
This type is not supported as injection token (any).
```

Comment: Why can't you inject the userService in base component?

Comment: Just pass ```userService``` in your ```super``` call like ```super(userService)```

Comment: @RiteshWaghela updated the question with the error. The error is actually with a type defined as `any`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, just change the constructor of the `BaseComponent` by adding `@Inject(String)` decorator to the `itemService`.

> [@Inject()](https://angular.io/api/core/Inject) Parameter decorator on a dependency parameter of a class constructor
> that specifies a custom provider of the dependency.

> [@Inject()](https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable) is a manual mechanism for letting Angular know that a
> parameter must be injected.

```js
constructor(@Inject(String) private itemService: any) {}
```